# Datetime Subtraction 'time data unavailable does not match format'

Tags: pandas, datetime

So I'm trying to calculate fulfillment time from the date a request is created until the link is generated.

I have some datetimes that look like this:

[image: 1]

I'm trying this to attempt to create a new column with the resulting fulfillment time:

```
hei_fix['Fulfillment Time'] = pd.to_datetime(hei_fix['Date Link Generated'], format='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S') - pd.to_datetime(hei_fix['Date Request Created'], format='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S')
```

It might appear like %H:%M:%S is incorrect as the image doesn't show seconds, but when double clicking the cell it displays the seconds as well. Additionally I have also checked, and it is a double-space between the date and time.

I currently get this error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Unavailable' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

Without the `%S`, I get this error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: :36
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about `pd.to_datetime(hei_fix['Date Link Generated'], format='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S', error='coerce')`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Just attempteed it and get this error:
TypeError: Object of type Timedelta is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was being stupid and didn't realise my dataset had "Unavailable" entries within my datetime columns. After accounting for and removing these, it now works as intended!